# How do I create global elements in a Django template that reference a database?

Tags: python, django-templates

I am working with the Django templating system as a beginner, and I had a question. Many times in web apps I have made in the past I have some sort of global element (as in its seen on almost all pages) on the page that references the database or active session.

An example of the active session would be someones name at the top of the page with a link to logout.

An example of the element that references the database would be a box that displays recent posting or login statistics.

With the templating system, it seems that the information available is primarily that which can be passed through as the "context". How can I go about achieving what I would like? Am I even thinking about how to construct things properly with Django or have I missed the point?

I apologize if this has been asked, I simply couldn't find a way to word it where I got results relevant to my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read the [Django Template Language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/) documentation.  In a nutshell, a context is a Python dictionary of name/value pairs, where the names are referenced in a template and the value is substituted for the name.  For example,

```
context = {'user': request.user}  # assign the current user to the context 'user'
return render_to_response('my_template.html', context)
```

will pass the current user to `my_template.html`.  Then, inside that template, `{{ user.name }}` will display that user's name.  The important thing is that you can reference the variable by the context name and treat it like a Python object (referencing the user's name as a attribute).

Comment: I see! But how would I have the global pieces I had mentioned?

Comment: If the global information is in a database, you would use Django's database queries to access that data and pass it to the template through the context.  You can also store global information in memcache.  In the example above, "user" is a record from the User table.